# Изучение программирования на C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Хочу научиться программировать на C#, а именно, интересует область по веб-программированию. Опыта в программирование нет. Максимум разбирался на уровне университетских методичек. Фактически с нуля буду браться за программирование. Определился с литературой, начну с книжки "Уотсон К. Visual C# 2008. Базовый курс.". Моя первая цель научиться основам базового программирования. Потом, непосредственно, буду переходить к веб-программированию. Под веб-программированием я имею виду изучение технологии asp.net, знакомство со скриптовыми языками, html и т.д. Для закрепления практики по основам программирование буду ограничиваться сперва упражнениями из книг. После прочтения и выполнения всех упражнений из книги поищу для себя интересный учебный проект и использую полученные знания на нем для закрепления навыков и поисков недостатков в полученных знаниях. Прошу по критиковать ход моих мыслей, посоветовать как и что лучше сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ход мыслей у вас нормальный, важно как можно быстрее начинать решать реальные задачи, успражнения из книг, опять так по своему опыту - не учат абсолютно ничему, по возможности надо их както видоизменять что бы их реализация вас как-то интересовала и обучение программированию не превращалось в не интересное и скучное занятие.

Вообще главная проблема всех начинающих программистов, на мой взгляд(да и наверное не только программистов), это лень. Если вы поставите цель и будете к ней идти то все у вас получится.

Еще как по мне важно не сравнивать себя с другими программистами, а также постраться как моно быстрее найти себе работу(причем мягко говоря не обязательно чтобы вам за нее платили), т.к. для любого программиста важно решать реальные задачи, а не примеры с учебников...

Удачи ;)

Comment: я не буду зацикливаться на упражнениях из книг. Я решу только те, которые есть в книге для изучения языка, знакомства с азами. А вот зацикливаться на реальных задачах я буду. Работу я думаю, что буду искать когда получу представление о данной области, идти без знаний как по мне не дело.

Comment: если хотите быстро этому обучится то у вас нет выбора, сидеть дома и ботанить можно очень долго...

Answer (score 0):

Все верно, если вы не будете отклоняться от своего курса, то все получится. Но вот получится ли не отклониться вопрос первый =)

А почему сразу не пытаетесь начать с ASP?

Книгу, кстати, поищите поновее ;-)

Comment: да, по поводу получится ли не отклониться это главный вопрос :)<br>
По поводу книги не считаю что сейчас для ТСа это принципиально т.к. вначале всеравно будут изучаться базы, хотя если подходить серьезно то наверное действительно стоит поискать чтонибудь поновее...

Comment: Я могу взять книгу по новое, например у Шилдта есть неплохая, но в ней нету упражнений. Я специально подбирал книгу с упражнениями. Я не начну сразу с asp, потому что не имею представления о C#. Я хочу понимать, что к чему. Вроде ж asp зависит от C#.

Answer (score -1):

В целом выглядит разумно. Но есть несколько замечаний:

1. Книжка по C# 2008 - советую взять поновее - хотя бы 2010 или 2012. Там много всякий штук появилось. Что касается самой книги, оценить не могу, так как не читал. Советую обратить внимание на этот список: http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/04/best-books-on-cnet.html
2. Asp.net, если подразумевается классический asp.net web forms устарел. Необходимость его детального изучения под большим вопросом. Хотя, местами его могут на собеседованиях спрашивать. В любом случае, его стоит посмотреть поверхностно, но особо разбирать я бы не стал. Лучше посмотреть asp.net mvc и web api.
3. html, js и css вполне можно изучать отдельно от C#. Советую обратить внимание на jQuery (по сути, библиотека для кроссбраузерной работы с dom'ом) и AngularJS (mvc-фреймвёрк преимущественно для реализации одностраничных приложений).

Да, что касается упражнений в книге - не уверен, что это существенно. Можно попытаться просто сделать что-то своё, либо полазить по форумам и посмотреть задаваемые там вопросы. Вообще, на мой взгляд, разнообразие вопросов на форумах повзоляет охватить различные аспекты намного шире, заглянуть в те области, о которых сам и не задумывался.

Comment: И кому же так нравится ставить минусы за ответы, что он даже не удосуживается написать комментарий, что ему не понравилось?